# How to set ssh tunnel to let a opened sever to connect to my internal server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a tomcat server on Mac computer A with IP `10.0.10.1` connected to my internal network. I can use my Mac computer B with IP `10.0.10.2` in the same network to access the webpage in `10.0.10.1:8080` but cannot access the web in another network. Now I have a public server in amazon EC2 with IP `52.x.x.x`.

If I want to set an ssh tunnel in my computer B to make other access `52.x.x.x:8080`, it will show the page the web in my computer A.

I have tried some methods like

```
ssh -i ~/LightsailDefaultPrivateKey1.pem -nfNTR *:8080:localhost:8080 ubuntu@52.x.x.x but it is now working, please help~Thank you
```